# mongo - get count of a intermediary document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

currently I have a query:

```
const result = await getInstances();
```

that provides me an array of document:

```
[{name: "first", age: 13},
{name: "second", age: 21},
{name: "third", age: 11},
{name: "fourth", age: 14}
...]
```

The query goes something like this:

```
...
return Instances.aggregate
         .match({//condition})
         .skip(skipValue).limit(pageSize) // pagination done here
```

I want a query that appends a count for the total no. of documents before the pagination, but returns the paginated data, e.g:

```
...
return Instances.aggregate
         .match({//condition}) ## I WANT THE COUNT OF THIS STEP TO BE APPENDED
         .<SOME_PIPELINE_HERE>
         .skip(skipValue).limit(pageSize) // pagination done here
```

would return something like:

```
{
  data: [{name: "first", age: 12}....<ALL_PAGINATED_DATA>],
  totalCount: 54  #count of data before pagination
}
```

*What I tried and didn't work:*

```
Instances.aggregate()
  .match({//CONDITION})
  .addFields({count: {$size: _id}})
  .skip(value).limit(value)
```

It seems it goes through and calculates this for each document instead of the whole

Comment: You can use `$facet` for it

Comment: @nimrodserok , but, using `$facet`, on one field I got to have the result of the intermediary query and not run a pipeline, how do I store the result of the previous query on the field?

Comment: For example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/sNfUnArvAVO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$facet` in order to "fork" the query in the middle, so the same data can be used on different pipelines. For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {a: {$in: [7, 8, 9]}}},
  {
    $facet: {
      total: [{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum: 1}}}],
      data: [{$skip: 1}]
    }
  },
  {$project: {data: 1, total: {$first: "$total.count"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sNfUnArvAVO)